# Cargar una grilla con hora

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

Tengo una consulta con respecto a cargar una grilla "GridView" , desde bd "sql server" tengo una tabla y tiene un campo datetime con fecha y hora acá viene mi pregunta y es donde necesito de su ayuda, cundo tengo que cargar una grilla con los datos de esa tabla pero solo con la hora y no con hora, fecha y en otra solo tengo que mostrar la fecha

El tema es como capturo el dato para decirle solo quiero ver la hora o la fecha

```
DateTime fechaHora = ((DateTime)lector[6]);
```

cundo me devuelve el lector quiero que en "fechaHora" solo pase la hora

```
STGrilla.Add(new SolicitudTramite(numero,E,NombreSolicitante, NombreEnt,codigo,Estado,fechaHora));
```

espero haberme echo entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se trata de un `gridview` nativo de ASP.NET, debes agregar o modificar el formato del atributo `DataFormatString` en el `asp:BoundField` correspondiente a la fecha.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CampoFecha" HeaderText="EncabezadoFecha" 
                DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm}"  />
```

Si el `gridview` es autogenerado, debes cambiar la fecha en el evento `ColumnAdded` del `gridview`:

```
private void MiGridView_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.ValueType == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        e.Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
    }
}
```

Comment: jotade te agradezco tu respuesta pero de esa forma agrego una columna mas a mi tabla que es autogenerada con los datos de la bd igual me sirve pero tengo que borrar la columna que se genera sola, espero se entienda

Comment: @martin.st edité la solución considerando tu implementación. Saludos.

Comment: jotade muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La solución que yo veo es que obtengas la hora del objeto y la metas en una variable con el formato deseado de la siguiente forma según tu código:

```
string hora = ((DateTime)lector[6]).ToString("H:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Antonio te cuento de esta forma si puedo darle el formato hora sin la fecha pero yo necesito pasar un datetime y para eso tengo que convertir se string en datetime y por defecto me va  a tomar la fecha del dia que es lo que no quiero una fecha, igual gracias por tomarte las molestias de contestar, gracias